# Code optimization, .mouseenter, .css - jQuery

Tags: jquery, optimization

I've made a slider using bxslider. It looks like in the picture. Everything works fine but if i try to use more than several sliders and move my mouse over the .slider-wrap few times then it's getting laggy thats why i need to make it work a little bit faster. How would you write this function ?[image]

```
sliderHover=function() {$(".slider-wrap").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find(".slide-desc, .slide-desc p, .slide-desc span, .slide-desc h2").css({left:'0'});
        $(this).find(".bx-wrapper").css({'padding-left':'100px'});
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find(".slide-desc").css({left:'-200px'});
        $(this).find(".bx-wrapper").css({'padding-left':'0'});
        $(this).find(".slide-desc p, .slide-desc span, .slide-desc h2").css({left:'500px'})}
)}

.slide-desc span, .bx-wrapper, .slide-desc, .slide-desc p, .slide-desc h2 {
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    -ms-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1); 
}
```

**@matewka**

```
$("#hide-menu-bg").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.slider-wrap').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    setTimeout(function(){sliderHover()},1400)
})
```

Forgot to write some more details, sorry about that. This slider is fully responsive, after you hide menu the content area maximizes its size. The above click function prevent slider to use mouseenter - important bug fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest getting rid of all that jQuery and use CSS `:hover`

```css
.bx-wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.slide-desc {
    left: -200px;
}
.slide-desc p, .slide-desc span, .slide-desc h2 {
    left: 500px;
}

.slider-wrap:hover .bx-wrapper {
    padding-left: 100px;
}
.slider-wrap:hover .slide-desc,
.slider-wrap:hover .slide-desc p,
.slider-wrap:hover .slide-desc span,
.slider-wrap:hover .slide-desc h2 {
    left: 0;
}
```

### Edit

As an addition to your edit, I'd suggest adding a class to the `.slider-wrap` when it's hovered instead of `:hover`

```css
.slider-wrap.hover .bx-wrapper {
    padding-left: 100px;
}
.slider-wrap.hover .slide-desc,
.slider-wrap.hover .slide-desc p,
.slider-wrap.hover .slide-desc span,
.slider-wrap.hover .slide-desc h2 {
    left: 0;
}
```

Then your jQuery might look as simple as this

```jquery
var sliderHover = function() {
    $(".slider-wrap").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('hover', 'mouseenter' == e.type);
    });
};
```

The second parameter in the `jQuery.toggleClass` method determines if the class should be added or removed. I put there a logic statement which returns `true` if the event was `mouseenter` or `false` otherwise.

Comment: I edited my answer according to your edit. Take a look please.